# Почему req.isAuthenticated из passposrtjs возвращает false на dev сервере?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

У меня есть проект на nodejs + express с авторизацией на passportjs.

Если я авторизуюсь на своем локальном хосте (localhost:3000) , то `req.isAuthenticated` возвращает `true` и сессия пользователя работает корректно.

но если сделать тоже самое на дев сервере, то сессия падает, так как `req.isAuthenticated` вернет `false`.

Пытались смотреть внутрь самих модулей, вроде все отрабатывает корректно. Код одинаковый и так и так, версии использованных модулей тоже.

Вот часть кода:

**express-session.js**

```
var session = require('express-session'),
express = require('express'),
RedisStore = require('connect-redis')(session);

var date = new Date;
date.setDate(date.getDate() + 30);

module.exports = session({
  secret: 'SECRET',
  resave: true, //don't save session if unmodified
  saveUninitialized: true, // create session until something stored
  expires: date.toUTCString(),
  cookie: {
    secure: false,
    httpOnly : true,
    maxAge : 30 * 60 * 1000 //30 minutes
  },
  rolling: true
});
введите сюда код
```

**login.js**

```
exports.post = function (req, res, next) {
passport.authenticate('local', { badRequestMessage: 'Error in your       fields' },
function (err, user, info) {
    if (err) return next(err);
    if (user) {
        req.logIn(user, function (err) {
            if (err) return next(err);
            return res.format({
                json: function () {
                    res.json({
                        link : '/personal/cabinet/'
                    });
                }
            });
        });
    } else {
        return res.format({
            html: function () {
                res.render('auth/login', {
                    error: info.message,
                    title: 'Login'
                });
            },
            json: function () {
                res.json(info);
            }
        });
    }
  }
  )(req, res, next);
};
```

**pasportjs**

```
var passport = require('passport'),
localStrategy = require('./strategy/localStrategy'),
models = require('models'),
Author = models.author;

//get user data for session
passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
Author.findOne({
  where: {
      id: user.id
  }
  }).then(function (user) {
    done(null, user);
  });
});

localStrategy(passport);

module.exports = passport.initialize();
```

**app.js**

```
...
app.use('bodyParserJson');
app.use('bodyParserUrldecoded');
app.use('cookieParser');
app.use(path.join('authPassport', 'session')); //express-session
app.use(path.join('authPassport', 'init')); //pasportjs
app.use(passport.session());
...
```

Версии: passport: 0.3.2, express-session: 1.13.0, express: 4.13.1, nodejs: 4.2.6

Подскажите в чем может быть проблема? Куда посмотреть детальней? Спасибо!

Comment: Так а пользователь, под которым вы пытаетесь авторизоваться существует на обоих серверах?

Comment: да существует, по запросам видно, что он находит пользователя, авторизует его, потом `req.isAuthenticated` возвращает true и после редиректа слетает

Comment: Если еще не разобрались: сделайте: 

console.log(req, req._passport, req._passport.instance._userProperty) 

перед вызовом req.isAuthenticated с двух серверов и сравните. Можно попробовать выложить на pastebin, чтобы мы тоже посмотрели